# In a commutative ring, GCD exists implies LCM exists?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, gcd-and-lcm

I am trying to prove the following :

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, $a,b\in R$; suppose $(a)+(b)$ is principal. Show that $(a)\cap(b)$ is principal.
> (Hint: first look at $R=\mathbb{Z}$ to gain some insight).

In $\mathbb{Z}$ if have $d=\gcd(a,b)$ then $(d)=(a)+(b)$, and if $m=\text{lcm}(a,b)$ then $(m)=(a)\cap(b)$ and $m=\displaystyle\frac{|ab|}{d}$, so my idea is to prove that $(a)\cap(b)=\displaystyle\Big(\frac{ab}{d}\Big)$ holds in $R$.

Since $(a)+(b)=(d)$ is principal we know that $\gcd(a,b)$ exists because:

$c|a,b\iff (a),(b)\subset (c)\iff (d)\subset (c)\iff c|d$.

If $(a)\cap(b)=(m)$ were to be principal then $\text{lcm}(a,b)$ would exist because:

$a,b|n\iff (n)\subset (a)\cap(b)=(m)\iff m|n$.

Now $d|a,b$ so $a,b|\displaystyle\frac{ab}{d}$ and $\displaystyle\Big(\frac{ab}{d}\Big)\subset(a)\cap(b)$. If $n\in(a)\cap(b)$ then $(dn)=((a)+(b))(n)=(an)+(bn)\subset (ab)$.

If $d$ **is not** a zero divisor then $dn\in (ab)\implies n\in\displaystyle\Big(\frac{ab}{d}\Big)$. However if $d$ **is** a zero divisor we cannot draw this conclusion.

**Question**: if $(a)+(b)=(d)$ is principal and $d$ is a zero divisor, can we still have that $(a)\cap(b)$ is principal?

I have seen (very closely) related questions discussed on this site, but they generally assume that $R$ is (at least) a domain. I am wondering if I'm missing something simple or if $R$ being a domain is really necessary and should be added to the statement I'm trying to prove. I've tried to prove this result by generalizing other identities between $\gcd$ and $\text{lcm}$ from $\mathbb{Z}$, but I always end up having to assume that $d$ is not a zero divisor to end the proof.

Comment: If there are zero-divisors, then what is (ab)/d? It is not uniquely defined.

Comment: $a = qd$, so $ab = qdb$, so it'd make sense to define $ab/d = qb$, since $b = rd$ also, you could define $ab/d = ar$, but $ar = qdr = qrd = qb$. So either definition works. Though with zero divisors, I agree we have to be careful.

Comment: Counterexamples for ideals: $\,R=\Bbb Z[x]\,$ we have $\,(2)+(3,x) = (1)\,$ so $\,(2)\cap (3,x) = (2)(3,x)\,$ and isn't principal. So it doesn't hold generally for ideals even in domains.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: sure, but $(3,x)$ isn’t principal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to effectively "cancel" $d$ at the *start* (vs. end) of proof. More precisely, since $\,d\mid a\,$ there exists $\,\frac{a}d\in R\,$ with $\,\frac{a}d\,d = a,\,$ and similarly for $\frac{b}d,\,\frac{n}d\,$ by $\,d\mid a,b\mid n.\,$ Fixing your proof this way:

$$\begin{align} (dn)&=((a)+(b))(n)=\,(an)\,+\,(bn)\subset (ab)\ \ \ \text{upon "cancelling"}\ d\\[.4em] 
{\rm we\ get}\ \ \color{#c00}{(n)} &= ((\frac{a}d)\!+\!(\frac{b}d))\:\!\color{#0a0}n  = (\frac{a}d\,n)\! +\! (\frac{b}d\,n) \subset  (\frac{a}d\,\frac{b}d\,d), \ \ {\rm by}\ \ a,b\mid n\\
{\rm and\ since\ \ \  } &\,\overbrace{((\frac{a}d)\!+\!(\frac{b}d))\, \color{#0a0}{d\,\frac{n}d}} = (\underbrace{(a)+(b)}_{\large (d)})\,\frac{n}d = \color{#c00}{(n)}.\ \ \ {\rm QED} \end{align}\qquad$$

Comment: Notice that the proof requires only the *existence* (not uniqueness) of the cofactors ("fractions") $\,\frac{a}d,\,\frac{b}d,\,\frac{n}d,\,$ i.e. $\,\frac{a}d\,$ denotes *any* solution of $\,d\,x = a,\,$ which exists by $\,d\mid a.\ $  We use fractional notation (vs. new variables) to avoid obfuscating the key scaling that relates the domain and non-domain proofs.

Answer (score 3):

Write $a=\alpha d$, $b=\beta d$, $d(u\alpha+v\beta-1)=0$, $\mu=\alpha\beta d$.

Let $c \in (a) \cap (b)$. Then $c=as=bt=dc’$ for $s,t \in A$. Thus $c\beta \in (\mu)$, $c\alpha \in \mu$, thus $uc\alpha+vc\beta=c’d(\alpha u+\beta v)=c’d=c \in (\mu)$. The reverse inclusion ($(\mu) \subset (a) \cap (b)$) is clear.

Comment: If I am not mistaken when you write $uc\alpha+vc\beta=c′d(\alpha u+\beta v)=c′d$ you are assuming that $\alpha u+\beta v=1$ from $d(uα+vβ−1)=0$ ? This does not hold if $d$ is a zero divisor, does it ? We can only conclude that $1-x\in (\alpha)+(\beta)$, where $x$ is s.t. $dx=0$.

Comment: No. I’m using the fact that $d(u\alpha+v\beta)=d$. So $c’d(u\alpha+v\beta)=c’d$, ie $u(c\alpha)+v(c\beta)=c$.